# Why doesn't a draggable container get rounded corners when dragging?

Tags: flutter

i am developing as a hobby, and is started on a card system where you can pull cards with text, i made my cards in a class of its own, with the following decoration:

```
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
  color: color,
  border: Borders.all(),
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.02)
)
```

And it works as it should except when im putting it in my draggable stack, and start dragging the card around, it looks like there is a white container behind it, but only when im dragging it, the code for the draggable is:

```
Draggable(
  child: card,
  feedback: Material(child:card),
  childWhenDragging: Container(),
  onDragEnd: (details) {setState(() {
    cards.remove(card);
  });}
),
```

Comment: You may have found an issue. I have tried all the Clipping techniques I could find and the same issue always happens with a Draggable.

Comment: Hmmm seems strange, so there is no way to achieve what im trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I solved it by adding the border radius tag to the Material widget, and then giving it the same border rules as the card decoration has